# Get ID of footer element

Tags: jquery

```
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
<div id="secondary" class="sidebar-container" role="complementary">
<div class="site-info">
</footer>
```

How to get this ID using jQuery?

I've tried:

```
jQuery('footer').attr('id');
```

but seems like not working. Why not?

Comment: Assuming you are closing those `div`'s, and are running the jQuery code after jQuery has been included on the page, I can't see an issue with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/kcxmczpr/

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're wrapped in a ready function:

```
$(function(){ 
   $('footer').attr('id');
   // or: $('.site-footer').attr('id');
});
```